# How to substract soup.find_all() in python 3

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I want to change the output of my `soup.find.all`. In the original source we have this:

```
<a href="/book/nfo/?id=4756888" class="ajax nfo"></a>
```

my `soup.find_all`:

```
href = [b.get('href') for b in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'.*\?id\=\d{4,8}'))]
```

gives me this:

```
/book/nfo/?id=4756888
```

but I want this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/book/download/?id=4756888
```

Comment: Is this the single url /book/nfo/ where you want to replace nfo with download?

Comment: How many other urls are there?

Comment: I have many other of anything url.

Comment: You will have to list all the urls to get a solution or atleast the common pattern which they all follow. But you might have got a clue on how to solve by reading the below answers.

Comment: the solution of  Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi  work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the properties of a [Python string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to add and replace parts to/from it:

```
a='/book/nfo/?id=4756888'
b = 'http://127.0.0.1' + a.replace('nfo', 'download')
print(b)
```

which gives:

```
'http://127.0.0.1/book/download/?id=4756888'
```

There's no need to use `regex` here.

Comment: You're right. But I was sure that he is going to bring in more urls :)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `http://127.0.0.1` in front and replace 'nfo' by 'download' using python's re.sub() function.

```
re.sub(r'pattern_to_match',r'replacement_string', string)
```

You can implement it as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a href="/book/nfo/?id=4756888" class="ajax nfo"></a>""")
c = ['http://127.0.0.1'+b.get('href') for b in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'.*\?id\=\d{4,8}'))]
print([re.sub(r'nfo',r'download',q) for q in c ])
```

Output:

```
['http://127.0.0.1/book/download/?id=4756888']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compile a regular expression and apply it in a list comprehension as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="/book/nfo/?id=4756888" class="ajax nfo"></a>', 'html.parser')
re_s = re.compile(r'(.*?\/)nfo(\/.*?)').sub
hrefs = [re_s('http://127.0.0.1' + r'\1download\2', a.get('href')) for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'.*\?id\=\d{4,8}'))]
print(hrefs)
```

Giving you:

```
['http://127.0.0.1/book/download/?id=4756888']
```